# Put a wood board on home wall concrete

Tags: concrete, wood, drill

My condo is made out of concrete. I like to put a wooden board up (~25mm thick, 600mm in width, and 1800mm in height) on my concrete wall so I can nail up the wall and load it on with tools (drivers, drills, wrenches etc.)

Questions:

1. How to locate if there are electrical wire running inside the concrete? I have no drawing of the condo. I have seen construction worker having a handheld device that beeps when they survey a concrete wall. Is that what it is and what is it called?
2. There are so many type of screws I found online that drill into concrete. For example, [this](https://www.confast.com/concrete-fasteners.aspx). The description wasn't very helpful and I wonder if someone can help tell me which screw I should use to drill through a wooden board and into a concrete wall

Answer (score 2):

1) To find wires buried near the surface in walls you can use a "cable detector" They have various names. One example is the Bosch PMD-7.

2) The type of screw depends partly on weight. For concrete, you could use a goodly number of tapcon screws or perhaps a fewer number of sleeve anchors. Check the weight rating of the screw and work out the expected load of your wooden panel plus all the things you will hang on it.

Answer (score -2):

There are many types of drill machine available in market for different types to do drill in concrete wall, but there is a difficulty to locate where the electric wire is going inside the concrete.